# Unity2d: Могу ли я из 1 спрайта сделать анимацию в которой будет несколько спрайта ВАЖНО: В 1 КАДРЕ

Tags: unity3d

[Вот 1 спрайт бочки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyxIW.png)
[У меня есть спрайты где бочка разделена на несколько частей](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD5YR.png)
Я хочу сделать из этих НЕСКОЛЬКИХ спрайтов анимацию разделения на несколько частей при уничтожении бочки
[На панели анимаций я немогу поставить в один кадр несколько спрайтов и анимировать их.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZziMb.png)
Вопрос в том, могу ли я вообще так сделать, если да, то как?

Несколько спрайтов нельзя наложить на 1 кадр анимации, принадлежавшей 1 анимации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй создать дочерние объекты (4 штуки) для своей бочки, к которым ты и добавишь спрайты со сломанными частями. При анимации ты сможешь включить или отключить отображение дочерних объектов когда тебе нужно, предварительно отключив спрайт основной (не уничтоженной) бочки.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!